# Javascript 'for' loop works incorrect when i put 'if' in it. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

```
var i;
function f_arrsmatch (array1,array2) {
    var error = 0;
    if(!array1 || !array2) { error++; }
    if(array1.length != array2.length) { error++; }
    for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if(array1[i] instanceof Array && array2[i] instanceof Array) {
            if(!f_arrsmatch(array1[i], array2[i])) { error++; }
        } else {
            if(array1[i] != array2[i]) { error++; }
        }
    }       
    return (error == 0);
}
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var arr2 = [[3,1,2],[1,3,2],[3,2,1]];
for(i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if(f_arrsmatch(arr1, arr2[i])) {
        alert('true');
    } else {
        alert('false');
    }
}
```

It shows alert with 'false' text only 1 time, but if I run this:

```
var i;
function f_arrsmatch (array1,array2) {
    var error = 0;
    if(!array1 || !array2) { error++; }
    if(array1.length != array2.length) { error++; }
    for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if(array1[i] instanceof Array && array2[i] instanceof Array) {
            if(!f_arrsmatch(array1[i], array2[i])) { error++; }
        } else {
            if(array1[i] != array2[i]) { error++; }
        }
    }       
    return (error == 0);
}
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var arr2 = [[3,1,2],[1,3,2],[3,2,1]];
for(i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    alert('something');
}
```

then browser alerts 3 times with text 'something'. Is it okay for js to be so weird or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Instead of a global `i` try declaring `i` for each loop `for (var i = 0;`. See if that makes a difference.

Comment: it worked, thanks. but i can't understand why if i run loop without 'if' it works another way.

Comment: Because the condition is predicted on `i` being a specific value. If you're reusing `i` from a previous loop it won't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function `f_arrsmatch`, the global variable i is re-evaluated. After the call of `f_arrsmatch`, the i is assigned as 3. Then to the next step of loop, the condition `i < arr2.length` is false, so the loop finish, thus the `alert` will be called only one time.